# Passing variable into expression predicate and getting unexpected results

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm not sure of the best way to ask the question so I'll try my best to explain...

I have a method I'm calling shown here:

```
public List<T> Get<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
{ ... }
```

when entering this method I'm expecting the value of expression to come in as {x => x.RecordNumber == 123456}

when I call it as follows it works as expected:

```
var customers = MyClass.Get<Customer>(x => x.RecordNumber == 123456);
```

However when I call it while trying to pass 123456 as a variable, something unexpected (to me) happens... So say I do:

```
long recordNumber = 123456;
var customers = _unitOfWork.Get<Customer>(x => x.RecordNumber == recordNumber);
```

then I get something along the lines of

```
{x => (x.RecordNumber == value(MyCallingClass+>c__DisplayClass2).recordNumber)}
```

which totally blows up what I'm trying to do.

How can I get my expected results by passing in a variable instead of a hard coded value? Has anyone seen this before and know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lambda syntax automatically sets up a closure if a variable is used in the lambda.  It seems like your `Get<T>` implementation is expecting an expression tree with a comparison with a numeric constant, but you want to be able to vary that number at the time of expression creation.

Two options:

1. Build the `Expression<Converter<T, bool>>` yourself, without using lambda syntax, and add an expression node for a numeric literal, passing the variable value you want.
2. Rewrite `Get<T>` to be able to handle an expression containing a variable reference, and get the numeric value from the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work unless the value is possibly going to change after the `Get`. However, if you want to handle this you should probably extract the value yourself and use that.

```
var thisIsYourValueExtractedImmediately = 
    Expression.Lambda((expression.Body as BinaryExpression).Right)
        .Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```

This obviously needs type checks, however it will immediately pull out your constant so that you can store it and use that value.